# Nested IF, moving AD computers

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I was writing a PS script to move computers in AD from one OU to another. 
The original code i had was this;

```
$pc = Get-ADComputer -Filter *

foreach($item in $pc)
{
if($item.operatingsystem -Like "Windows XP*")
{
    if($item.name -Like "*-B-*")
        {
            move-ADObject -Identity $item -TargetPath 'ou=myou,DC=mydomain,dc=com'
        }

    else if($item.name -Like "*-K-*")
        {
            move-ADObject -Identity $item -TargetPath 'ou=myou,DC=mydomain,dc=com'
        }
}
else if($item.operatingsystem -Like "Windows 7*")
{
    if($item.name -Like "*-B-*")
        {
            move-ADObject -Identity $item -TargetPath 'ou=myou,DC=mydomain,dc=com'
        }
    else if($item.name -Like "*-K-*")
        {
            move-ADObject -Identity $item -TargetPath 'ou=myou,DC=mydomain,dc=com'
        }
}
}
```

The code ran but didn't actually do anything. I edited it to this and it did what i intended it to do;

```
$pcw7 = Get-ADComputer -Filter {operatingsystem -Like "Windows 7*"}
$pcwinxp = Get-ADComputer -Filter {operatingsystem -Like "Windows XP*"}



foreach($item in $pcw7)
{
if($item.Name -Like "*-B-*")
        {
            move-ADObject -Identity $item -TargetPath 'ou=myou,DC=mydomain,dc=com'
        }

    elseif($item.Name -Like "*-K-*")
        {
            move-ADObject -Identity $item -TargetPath 'ou=myou,DC=mydomain,dc=com'
        }
}

foreach($item in $pcwinxp)
{
if($item.Name -Like "*-B-*")
        {
            move-ADObject -Identity $item -TargetPath 'ou=myou,DC=mydomain,dc=com'
        }

    elseif($item.Name -Like "*-K-*")
        {
            move-ADObject -Identity $item -TargetPath 'ou=myou,DC=mydomain,dc=com'
        }
}
```

Can someone help me explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming $pc has objects.

Check the default properties returned by get-ADComputers, I'm not sure the operatingsystem property is returned by default. Try the first script with :

```
 $pc = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties operatingsystem
```

This will force PowerShell to get you the default properties + the operatingsystem property of the objects.

The reason the second script works is, because you use "operatingsystem" as a filter. It automatically includes this as part of the properties returned.

Comment: You are correct; the OperatingSystem property is not returned by default.